# How to label lists?

Tags: listings, lists, enumerate

How do I implement what is shown below? If I just use "enumerate" each time, it doesn't get labeled (only the items get labeled).

[image]

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item \begin{enumerate}
  \item A dated B $\Leftrightarrow$ B dated A
  \item A hibernated with B $\Leftrightarrow$ B hibernated with A
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading `enumitem` makes it easy to have a custom layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=(\arabic*), labelsep=1.35em}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{label=\alph*., align=left, labelsep=1em}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{enumerate}
 \item \begin{enumerate}
 \item Mary dated $\Leftrightarrow$ John dated Mary
 \item Mary hibernated with John $\Leftrightarrow$ John hibernated with Mary
 \item Mary is John’s cousin $\Leftrightarrow$ John is Mary's cousin
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But if I use it two times in a row, then, as far as I can see, the second list also will get labeled as (1). I would like the second list to be labeled as (2), the third as (3), and so on. Sorry, I didn't state it explicitly in the question...

Comment: @user181940: `\begin{enumerate}
 \item \begin{enumerate}
 \item Mary dated $\Leftrightarrow$ John dated Mary
 \item Mary hibernated with John $\Leftrightarrow$ John hibernated with Mary
 \item Mary is John’s cousin $\Leftrightarrow$ John is Mary's cousin
 \end{enumerate}
  \item \begin{enumerate}
 \item Mary dated $\Leftrightarrow$ John dated Mary
 \item Mary hibernated with John $\Leftrightarrow$ John hibernated with Mary
 \item Mary is John’s cousin $\Leftrightarrow$ John is Mary's cousin
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}` should work as expected.

Comment: What do you mean with ‘use it twice in a row’? What do you call a row in this context?

Comment: @leandriis But in this case the two lists are within one "enumerate" environment, so I cannot insert a text between them. What if I want one list to appear at the beginning of the document, and the second at the end, at the same time having some text between them?

Comment: then have a look at the `resume` key.

Comment: @Bernard I mean  `\begin{enumerate}
 \item \begin{enumerate}
 \item Mary dated $\Leftrightarrow$ John dated Mary
 \item Mary hibernated with John $\Leftrightarrow$ John hibernated with Mary
 \item Mary is John’s cousin $\Leftrightarrow$ John is Mary's cousin
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}\begin{enumerate}
 \item \begin{enumerate}
 \item Mary dated $\Leftrightarrow$ John dated Mary
 \item Mary hibernated with John $\Leftrightarrow$ John hibernated with Mary
 \item Mary is John’s cousin $\Leftrightarrow$ John is Mary's cousin
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}`

Comment: I see. As @leandriis said, you have the `resume` or `resume*` keys (the latter uses the same settings).. In case there are in between other lists which should not be taken into account for the counter, you have the key  `series= whatever name you please`, then for the other lists of the same series, use the key `resume(*)=series_name`.

Comment: @Bernard I'm not sure where to insert `resume`. I tried googling it, but Google only finds things like "8 ways to write your resume/CV in latex".

Comment: Like this: `begin{enumerate}[resume] \item ....... \end{enumerate}`. Is it clear?

Comment: Yes, it's clear, thanks!

Comment: Oh, is it possible to cite a list by its number? It looks like `\label` and `ref` do not work directly. Or should I post a separate question?

Comment: Do you mean referring to an item in the list?

Comment: I meant the whole lists. E.g. "consider the second sentence in (2)".  Also, I just noticed that  `resume` doesn't seem to work when the lists are located in different sections.

Comment: Isn't (2) the second item in the first level list? Never noticed that `resume` has to be used in the same section (unless some specification in the  code resets the enumerate counter at each section).

Comment: The lists are labeled as (1), (2), (3),... Each list (n) has items a., b., c., ... in it. I would like to cite list (n) for some n. Regarding `resume`, I figured it out (I used `series` you mentioned).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99217/discussion-between-bernard-and-user181940).